# CSS and JS not loading after pushing to Openshift from Cloud9 IDE

Tags: javascript, css, git, openshift, cloud9-ide

I am creating an a webpage with bootsrap signin/signup functionalities. In my Cloud9 IDE, the bootsrap css and js are loading properly and the page looks good. But, when I push the code to Openshift using:

```
git commit -a -m 'newchange' 
git push
```

the HTML code is rendering but with no Bootstrap css and JS. Here is my Openshift link: [App link](http://customapp281project-cmpw281.rhcloud.com/)

Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Look in the browsers dev tools. The css and js can't be found

Comment: yeah, I saw that too but I am not sure why this is happening in Openshift only. The same code with the same folder structure works fine in CloudIDE.

Comment: What is the url you use on cloudIDE? Did you commit the css and js files (maybe you had to in order for them to be in cloudIDE, I don't know)

Comment: I explicitly added the css and js folders using git add css/ js/, and then commit + push. Still no luck.. :(

Comment: I assume you can view the working site on cloudIDE. If you inspect that site what URL are the CSS and is being served from. I'm looking for something in the path that is different, maybe an extra component or something

Comment: did you git add the css & js files on cloud9? Try using the 'git status' command to see if you have any files that need to be added.